# Finding $A$ such that $R'=ARA^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Well i no this a silly question but i just want to know. There are two matrices $R'$ and $R$. We know that $R'$ is a diagonal matrix and we know $R$ and we also know that $R$ is a symmetric matrix. Now we have to find a matrix $A$ such that

$R'$=$ARA^{T}$

I can solve it in brute force method but  I am sure there is another clever method to solve this one.We know that all the matrices are 3X3 matrices

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If all matrices are real and if you don't mind $A$ being orthogonal, then what you've written down is no more and no less than the orthogonal diagonalization of the symmetric matrix $R$, which is described in great detail in pretty much any textbook on linear algebra.

Comment: it's kind of the inverse of diagonalization of a BILINEAR FORM.

Comment: You might use the spectral decomposition of $R$ to get your $A$. Note that for this problem to be solvable: you need both $R$ and $R'$ to have the same rank. Also, if your matrices are real and you want a real $A$, they need to have the same inertia (numbers of negative, zero, and positive eigenvalues).